# How to split markers on Google Static Map on same address?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-static-api

In My application I have to show split of markers which means all markers should be visible.  If one marker geo distance  is longer than others it should show like below.

[image]

**In Google Dynamic Map API** which is possible by “Spiderfier”.  Refer the link below and below image.

http://jawj.github.io/OverlappingMarkerSpiderfier/demo.html

[image]

Like this option, I have to split of all markers in **Google Static MAP API**.

Any possibilities  there to visible all markers ?

Static Map URL:
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?sensor=false&channel=Resivalue&scale=2&center=29.900598698735365,-95.69396430030821&zoom=13&size=1300x500&maptype=roadmap&markers=color:green%7Clabel:S%7C29.89357,-95.68815999999998&markers=color:pink%7Clabel:1%7C29.893167,-95.68737599999997&markers=color:pink%7Clabel:2%7C29.893904,-95.688424&markers=color:pink%7Clabel:3%7C29.892301,-95.68776500000001&markers=color:pink%7Clabel:4%7C29.892343,-95.68866200000002&markers=color:pink%7Clabel:5%7C29.894404,-95.689029&markers=color:pink%7Clabel:6%7C29.893235272621563,-95.68611836505124&markers=color:pink%7Clabel:7%7C29.892402,-95.68687699999998&markers=color:pink%7Clabel:8%7C29.891934,-95.688918&markers=color:pink%7Clabel:9%7C29.919640547998576,-95.72656616430663

Comment: You need to do all that in the URL that requests the static map.  What does your current static map URL look like?

Comment: @geocodezip , I have updated my question. Please have a review and help me out.

Comment: Still don't see the static map URL.  Please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: Hi @geocodezip. I have added the static map URL.

Answer (score 0):

As stated [here](https://www.gavick.com/blog/google-static-maps-api)

Google Static MAP API Disadvantages :

1. The main disadvantage is the lack of a map interactivity – if we
   need a map to scale, move or if we need to roll down a window after
   clicking on a marker; Google Static Maps is not a solution for us.
2. URL address of a map has a restricted length (2048 symbols) which
   sometimes may make impossible to present all needed content on a
   map.
3. Limits also apply in the case of own images markers placing on a map
   – in this case it is 4096pixels (64 x 64 px).